# Animation of Histograms in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, histogram

I am working on creating an animation of multiple histograms in Python, however I am unable to do so. I have tried using plt.pause and the time.sleep commands available on python, but to no success. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import math
import random
from numpy import zeros
from time import sleep
m = 1
g = 9.8
b = 0.1
A = math.sqrt((m*g)/b)
f=1000
a=[0]*f
z=np.zeros(f)

def velocity(tvel, vvel):
    return(A - (math.pow(vvel,1)/A)+(random.randint(-500,500)))
for k in range(0,f):
    endtime = 100
    steps = 1000
    h = endtime/steps
    timearr = np.linspace(0,endtime,steps)
    vIni = 0
    v = vIni
    varr= []
    for t in timearr:
        varr.append(v)
        v1 = h*velocity(t,v)
        v2 = h*velocity((t+(h/2)), (v+(v1/2)))
        v3 = h*velocity((t+(h/2)), (v+(v2/2)))
        v4 = h*velocity((t+(h/2)), (v+(v3/2)))
        v = v+((1.0/6.0)*(v1+(2*v2)+(2*v3)+v4))
    xrandom=np.zeros(len(varr))
    xrandom[0]=0
    c=0

    for i in range(0,len(varr)-1):
        c=c+((varr[i]+varr[i+1])/2)*0.01
        xrandom[i+1]=c
    a[k]=xrandom
for o in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(0,f):
        z[i]=a[i][o]
    plt.hist(z,bins=150,normed=True)
plt.show()
```

Essentially what this code does is that it plots 1000 different histograms. What I would like to do is create an animation that will show each histogram after the other (in order) with a fixed frame with relevant bounds. How should I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean of animation of histogram?

Comment: Have you tried using animated histograms from matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/animation/animated_histogram.html